# Como devolver una tabula de un montículo en un formato decimal?

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer un metodo que utilisemos cuando construimos un `Heap` (Montículo)
para hacer un estructura de datos del tipo árbol con información perteneciente a un conjunto ordenado. Quiero hacer un montículo minimo. Lo contrario son monticulos maximos : tienen la característica de que cada nodo padre tiene un valor mayor que el de cualquiera de sus nodos hijos :

[image: Monticulo maximo]

Quiero muestrar los resultados contenidos en la tabulacion en `main.cpp`. Hizo :

```
cout<<"enter no of elements of array\n"<<endl;
cin>>size;
Heap* heap = new Heap(size);
cout << heap->GetArray();
```

Aqui esta el GetArray() en `heap.h` :

```
int* GetArray() const {return array;}
```

Pero me da el terminal :

```
$ ./main
enter no of elements of array

4
enter element: 4
1
enter element: 3
2
enter element: 2
3
enter element: 1
4
enter element: 0
5
0x1c3246
```

- Pienso que esta en hexadecimal. Pueden ayudarme devolver las valores
  en formato decimal ?
- En caso contrario pienso que esta en una casa de memoria pero hizo

:

```
int* GetArray() const {return *array;}
```

y

```
int* GetArray() const {return &array;}
```

Y ninguna funciona.

---

Aqui esta como se cree el Monticulo en heap.cpp :

```
// array version
#include "heap.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

Heap::Heap(int size):size(size),array(new int[size])
{
    build_minheap(size);
}

Heap::~Heap()
{
    delete[] array;
}


// aqui nos anadimos los numerosos
void Heap::build_minheap(int i)
{   
int entier;

    for(i=size;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout << "enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
        cin >> entier;
        min_heapify(entier);
    }

}

// aqui nos organisamos el Montículo binario por minimos
void Heap::min_heapify(int i)
{

    int j, temp;

    temp = array[i];
    j=2*i;
    while(j<=size)
    {
        if(j<size && array[j+1] <array[j])
            j= j+1;
        if(temp<array[j])
            break;
        else if (temp >=array[j])
        {
            array[j/2]=array[j];
            j=2*j;
        }
    }

    array[j/2]=temp;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int* GetArray() const;
```

A partir de la declaración que te he puesto, ¿eres capaz de saber el número de elmentos del arreglo que devuelve? Yo desde luego no lo se, tu tampoco y el compilador, obviamente tampoco y es por eso que cuando haces:

```
cout << heap->GetArray();
```

El programa únicamente puede limitarse a imprimir la dirección de memoria a la que apunta el arreglo.

¿Quieres imprimir todos los elementos? Entonces tendrás que iterar manualmente el arreglo para generar la salida:

```
int* array = heap->GetArray();
for( int i=0;/* ... */; i++ )
  std::cout << array[i];
```

El comentario en el bucle está porque con la información que publicas es imposible saber de qué forma se puede llegar a conocer el tamaño del array.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! La sobre el tamaño del array fue en el main y preguntado al usario en un `size`...

Comment: @Marine1 no se si te he entendido, pero hacer `sizeof(heap->GetArray())` no te va a permitir conocer el número de elementos. Lo digo por si acaso